# How to change color of bing maps pushpin for windows store app

Tags: javascript, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, windows-phone-8.1, winjs

I want to change the color of my pushpin. I am trying to set the icon property but im getting a cross mark rather than a pushpin. The image is my project folder.

```
  var targetPin = new Microsoft.Maps.Pushpin({

                            latitude: searchLocations[i].locationLatitude,
                            longitude: searchLocations[i].locationLongitude,
                            height: 44,
                            width: 30
                        },{   icon:'images/green.png'});
```

Comment: try icon:'ms-appx:///images/green.png'

Answer (score 0):

In the image's properties, set the build action to "content".

Comment: there is only package content and thats already set to "none"

Comment: sorry typo, thats set to content